# IFERROR not working for list validation in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, data-validation

I am using list validation on two drop-down-lists, with the options in second one dependent on the selected option in the first. I have created the following named ranges:

```
WritingUtensils = { Pencil, Marker, Chalk, Pen }

Pencil = { Mechanical Pencil, Regular Pencil, Colored Pencil }

Pen = { Ballpoint, Fountain }
```

In the data validation screen, I define the source for the first drop-down-list cell as

```
=WritingUtensils
```

The `INDIRECT` function will be called on the selected value of the first drop-down-list to populate the second one. However, if the named range does not exist (e.g., the user has selected Marker or Chalk), the second drop-down list should only provide blank/empty option.

To do this, I have assigned a new named range called `Blank` to a single empty cell.

Here is the formula for my second drop-down-list source:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT($A$1), Blank)
```

where A1 is the cell containing the first drop-down-list.

It gives the error message

> The source currently evaluates to an error.

and the second drop-down-list never shows any options. Why is this happening? I expected using `IFERROR(...)` would ensure the source never evaluates to an error.

Comment: Sure you want to use IFERROR? What about if blank? In looking further into IFERROR, the format is IFERROR(value, value_if_error), so asking for IFERROR to handle a name-Range of Blank wouldn't be a "value".

Comment: I've done this so many times I've created a full-blown VBA solution for this type of problem. If you feel like your use case will grow to be more complex than the examples in your question, check out [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/1137213/how-can-i-implement-dynamic-dependent-data-validation-list-in-excel/1137260#1137260)