# Using data validation to list a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I have a workbook with a table that has headers with names and group. The names column is distinct (no name is repeated) whilst the group column has values (like G1, G2, G3 etc) which are repeated.
I want to create 2 lists, the first one of which will allow the user to select a group. The second list will then allow him to select a name from that group.
Is this possible? I have been trying to get a solution that works but it seems all of them require that the row values in my group column need to be changed into headers

Edit: More details
Not able to post images due to rep. Here is a link to the setup 
The first image shows the data sheet with a table with names, group and ID.
[image]

On the user sheet i want to add a data validation list for both group and names. The user selects a group like G2, then under names he gets a list of the people who are in G2 and can select whomever he wants
[image]

Comment: You need Dependable Drop Down method for Validation !

Comment: @RajeshS i understand that part, im having problem implementing it as the examples i have seen online require the list sheet to have separate tables for Group and Names. I want them to be in the same table as i want to use VlOOKUP later.

Comment: If you could have each group in a separate table, you could do like in the following example: https://superuser.com/questions/1137213/how-can-i-implement-dynamic-dependent-data-validation-list-in-excel but maybe that's not an option.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what you are trying to achieve. What is supposed to happen once the user selects name and group? If names are unique, why both selecting a group, since (presumably) only one group will be associated with any given name.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber i'm trying to keep the table as one and not separate if that is at all possible

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad i have edited the question to hopefully  reflect better what i'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**Note:** *Since your **Ids and Names** are resembling to Cell/Row references, therefore instead of standard method, I would like to suggest use an Array Formula to create Dependant Drop Down List.*

**How it works:**

- Select Cell **E72** & From **DATA Tab** click 
  **Data Validation** then hit **Settings** and 
  fill values as shown in Screen shot below &
  finish with **Ok**.

[image]

- Enter this Array (CSE) Formula in cell **A83**, 
  finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill down.

`{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$72:$A$80,SMALL(IF($C$72:$C$80=$E$72,ROW($A$72:$A$80)-MIN(ROW($A$72:$A$80))+1),ROWS($A$83:A83))),"")}`

- Enter this Array (CSE) Formula in cell 
  **C83**, and finish with 
  **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

  `{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$72:$B$80,SMALL(IF($A$72:$A$80=$G$72,ROW($B$72:$B$80)-MIN(ROW($B$72:$B$80))+1),ROWS($C$83:C83))),"")}`
- Select cell **G72** reach to **Data 
  Validation**, click **Settings** and fill 
  values as shown in Screen Shot below.

[image]

- Finally select cell **I72** reach to **Data 
  Validation**, click **Settings** and fill 
  `$C$83:$C$83` for **Source** then finish with 
  **Ok**.

**N.B.**

- Now, start clicking **Group** from `1st Drop 
  Down` then you find related **Names** in `2nd 
  Drop Down`, click any, finally you find **Id** 
  in `3rd Drop Down`.
- Later on you may hide `A82:C85`.

*Adjust Cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, this does the job. I had never known about array formulas before. I learnt something new today which is always a plus!

Comment: @John,, glad to help you ,, keep asking ☺