# using excel data validation to subset data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to extract data from a table based on row (letter) names; e.g. the following table has one of 3 unique letters in each row: A, B, or C.

[image]

I want to set data validation for each of these unique letters; for instance, A with a "Yes or No" data validation option and so on. When I select "Yes" for any of the variables (i.e. letters), the data from the original table will be copied to a separate table in the worksheet; e.g. if I select A (Yes), B (No), and C (Yes), the new filtered table will have a total of 4 rows summing 12 instead of 31 when all data are selected.

In the [attached excel file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17xQHQTBsPGf_ViWALGoEnD9KCEzrEVuF/view?usp=sharing), I built an example where I only have a single data validation cell to select one of the three letters to subset the data. What I am looking instead is an option to have "yes/No" for each of these three letters. I am trying to use VLOOKUP to get it work, but any other solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this link https://superuser.com/questions/1414506/using-data-validation-to-list-a-column/1414733#1414733 recently I've posted solution will help You !

Comment: What about a pivot table?